# Questions regarding a diode and a resistor in series

Tags: diodes

[image]

For the first question, I believe that the diode is shorted.

My reason is: Since the voltage across the diode is positive (i.e 5V), the current will flow in the circuit, since current flows in the direction that the triangle/arrow is pointing, therefore making the diode act as a shorted element.

In this case, the diode is forward biased.

For the second question I think the diode voltage will be zero, and the diode would still act normally.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework without any effort to solve it.

Comment: Not really an homework, and have being able to solve the first one, after much research, I just needed to confirm my answers . I just needed to learn from the masters . just because it's a picture doesn't mean its home work, thanks

Comment: I don't see any answers

Comment: @JimmyHope Great, press on "edit" and write your attempt and where you've reached. Further, use schematic tool to draw your circuit and **type** your question instead of snapping it.

Comment: @pipe , my answers have gotten so far have being added

Comment: @hazeem , am not too conversant with the schematic tool, and I am struggling with it on my phone ,as I don't have a laptop

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Unfortunately, you don't specifically ask a question here. To avoid question closure, you need to reformat this as a specific *question*, not "please check this over".

Comment: "a) Suppose the voltage **across the diode** of Figure 1 is 5V, is the diode open or shorted?" It will be open because it will be broken very soon if there are really 5V **across the diode** in forward direction. With the given circuit, however,  there won't be 5V **across the diode**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Question A is impossible - if you are dealing with a real diode, the maximum forward voltage across a 1N4001 will be about 0.7 volts - not 5 volts.

for question B, if the 5 volt source can supply sufficient current, the diode will vanish in a puff of smoke.

Comment: Question A is what you get after question B.

Comment: No, read the whole question A.  It is a valid question and not impossible.  Consider it a trouble-shooting question if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

**A:** The diode is open. An open circuit means there is no path to ground. If the diode is broken (i.e. open), and there is no path to ground, the voltage across it will be 5V. This is essentially the same as removing the element altogether.

**B:** If the resistor shorts, the diode would be connected directly to the source, so there would be 5V across it. It would then pop, and you would back to part A.

**C**. The diode has shorted (for whatever reason).

Answer (score 0):

@ Jimmy

Here is a loadline, the powerful way to visualize such a nonlinear 2-element circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsLLQB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @analohsystemsrf, but I do not know how to apply the graph to the question asked